# ObjC string/char manipulation + parsing

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring, char

The following piece of code is supposed to return two integers: val1 = 2 and val2 = 5.

```
    NSString *col = @"1245DD";

    char c1 = [col characterAtIndex:1];
    char c2 = [col characterAtIndex:3];

    int val1 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:&c1] intValue];
    int val2 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:&c2] intValue];
```

inspecting values at runtime:

- c1 = '2'
- c2 = '5'

good so far.

But then:

- val1 = 2
- val2 = 52

I don't understand why val2 always ends up being the concatenation of c2 and c1. What am I missing?
thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an `NSString` object as a UTF-8 string, that is in fact a single character.  You need to NUL-terminate the UTF-8 string if you want to use it like this.

Note that `[NSString characterAtIndex:]` returns a `unichar`, not a `char`, so use `[NSString initWithCharacters:length:]` instead where you can tell the method how many characters to use:

```
NSString col = @"1245DD";

unichar c1 = [col characterAtIndex:1];
unichar c2 = [col characterAtIndex:3];

int val1 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&c1 length:1] intValue];
int val2 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&c2 length:1] intValue];
```

Comment: Indeed, missing the & ;-) Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: `val1 = c1 - '0';` would also do it, I think. The unichars superset the chars and ASCII arranged the numbers contiguously and in ascending order

Comment: @Jem No, that wasn't the broken bit (the *name* of an array is the address of its first element).  It was broken elsewhere...